# Lodash search by startswith in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, lodash

I'm creating a simple search that searches an array of objects that starts with a string passed from an input.

So I have this:

```
var items = [
    {id: 1, tags: ['foo']},
    {id: 2, tags: ['fish', 'ball']},
    {id: 3, tags: ['bar', 'goo']},
];

input.on(function(e) {
    var test = _.filter(items, function(item) {
         return _.includes(_.pluck(items, 'tags'), input.val());
    });
    console.log(test);
});
```

This always returns an empty array, I think i'm missing `startsWith`, how do I use it here in my implementation:

**The expected output should be:**

```
input: 'f'
output: [{id: 1, tags: ['foo']}, {id: 2, tags: ['fish', 'ball']}]
```

since the two items have tags that starts with `f`

Comment: What to you mean by startsWith? Could you add expected output of the method?

Comment: alright..i'll add the expected output..

Comment: What about if input is b? bar goo for sure and how about fish ball?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Basically, you do not need lodash for that:

```
var test = items.filter(function (item) {
  return item.tags.some(function (tag) {
    return 0 === tag.indexOf(input.val());
  });
});
```

But if you like, you can use it

```
var test = _.filter(items, function (item) {
  return _.some(item.tags, function (tag) {
    return _.startsWith(tag, input.val());
  });
});
```

Comment: simple and elegant answer (:

Comment: So, if there were multiple arrays to search through, for example tags[] && names[], would you break up the above to iterate through both, or is there a better lodash approach for that type of scenario?

Comment: Concatenate them and search in the result if they are small. Save the search function into var and search in each and then concatenate the result if they are big. Lodash is not a big helper in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$(function(){
var items = [
    {id: 1, tags: ['foo']},
    {id: 2, tags: ['fish', 'ball']},
    {id: 3, tags: ['bar', 'goo']},
];

var input = $('input:first');
input.on('input', function(e) {
    var test = _.filter(items, function(item) {
         for(var t in item.tags) {
           if(item.tags[t].indexOf(input.val())==0) {
             return true;
           }
         }
  
         return false;
    });
    console.log(test);
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lodash/lodash/3.10.0/lodash.min.js"></script>

<input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var items = [
    {id: 1, tags: ['foo']},
    {id: 2, tags: ['fish', 'ball']},
    {id: 3, tags: ['bar', 'goo']}
];

input.on(function(e) {
    var test = _.filter(items, function(item) {
        return _.chain(items.tags)
                .map(_.partial(_.startsWith, _, input.val()))
                .any()
                .value();
    });
    console.log(test);
});
```